# Neural network with multiple inputs from various angles, contradictory features

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification

Is there a way for the neural network to communicate with each other. I.E. An image of a rectangular prism can look like a cube from one perspective, but as soon as it's rotated, we know it's a rectangular prism.

Is there a way for the neural network to communicate with itself such that when it sees "oh it's a rectangular prism" it disregards it's first thought that it's a cube?